# Wordpress custom class not in the source code

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a problem with wordpress.

I have a post with a simple 
`<div class"codeTutoriel_intermediaire">Intermediaire</div>` 
to make a test.

When I look at the source code in chrome, I don't see the class `codeTutoriel_intermediaire` to the div. So the css does not work because the class is not there.

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you have added the code: `<div class"codeTutoriel_intermediaire">Intermediaire</div>` through the `Visual` tab of WordPress post editor, it will be converted to HTML entities. Use the `Text` tab to include codes like these.